# What is the difference between Node.bind() and Template Binding

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am reading the docs of Google Polymer,there are two types of data binding,Node.bind() and Template Binding,so, what is the difference between Node.bind() and Template Binding

Comment: What is "Node.bind()"?  What is this about?

Comment: @Pointy Node.bind() is part of Polymer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both ways of achieving data-binding. One in the context of DOM nodes and the other in the context of templates.

### Node.bind()

`Node.bind()` allows you to tell DOM nodes to bind a named property to some data that you provide. So below, we're binding the property `value` (object.path.to.value) to the `.textContent` in our textNode.

```
var obj = {
  path: {
    to: {
      value: 'hi'
    }
  }
};

var textNode = document.createTextNode('mytext');
textNode.bind('textContent', obj, 'path.to.value');
```

This is neat because anytime `value` changes, `Node.bind()` keeps your `.textContent` updated.

### TemplateBinding

The Polymer docs state that this extends what you can do with the HTML `<template>` tag - specifically, giving you access to four new attributes: `bind`, `repeat`, `if` and `ref`.

So let's say that we wanted to pass a propery `foo` to a `<template>` which we would like to use in our template content, but want to keep in sync so that anytime `foo` changes, the template also gets updated. With `bind` that's as straight-forward as:

```
<template bind="{{ foo }}">
  Creates a single instance with {{ foo }} when singleton model data is provided.
</template>
```

`repeat` is really useful for when you're working with lists or collections of data - like users:

```
<template repeat="{{ user in users }}">
  <li>{{user.name}}</li>
</template>
```

`if` is really handy for conditional values in templates:

```
<template if="{{ conditionalValue }}">
  Binds if and only if conditionalValue is truthy. (same as *bind if*)
</template>
```

and so on. You can find more examples of what can be done with these attributes in the [TemplateBinding](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/template.html) docs.

Comment: I agree with the saying - "they have different contexts"